# Having trouble updating a users details with JPARepository and UserService

Tags: java, spring

I am a bit stuck in my code as I do not know how to continue on with my implementation of a method for changing a users details. I think its a pretty simple issue but I am a begginer in java and springboot and I have run out of ideas on how to fix it.

I have **IUserService.java**:

```
public interface IUserService {

    User registerNewUserAccount(UserDto userDto);

    List<User> findAll();

    Optional<User> findById(Long id);

    public void delete(Long id);

    public User updateConfirmed(Long id);
}
```

The **UserService.java** method where I am having the problem:

```
@Override
public User updateConfirmed(Long id) {
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(id); // I tried to do User user = userRepository.findById(id); but it did not work here and my IDE wanted to do Optional instead
    if (user.confirmed == true) //cannot resolve user.confirmed
    {
        user.confirmed = false; //cannot resolve user.confirmed
    }
    else {
        user.confirmed = true; //cannot resolve user.confirmed
    }
    return userRepository.save(user); //Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.lukas.ramonas.cms.Model.User'
}
```

Any tips on how to fix this? Thanks!

Edit. **SOLUTION**

By using the suggested fix by *Stefan Freitag* I've fixed my issue. Instead of using user I have to use *user.get()*. This is my implementation of the fix:

```
@Override
public User updateConfirmed(Long id) {
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(id);
    if (user.get().getConfirmed() == true)
    {
        user.get().setConfirmed(false);
    } else {
        user.get().setConfirmed(true);
    }
    return userRepository.save(user.get());
}
```

Comment: `user` is of type `Optional`  and the `confirmed` belongs to type `User`. Please have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html - accessing the user would be possible eg. via he Optional.get() call. You could also go with Optional.orElseThrow(...) as a user with the id may not be existing.

Comment: Not sure if added the required annotations for the framework to pick up the repository classes. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.java-config

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I have used optional.get() and fixed my issue.  I'll update the post with the solution I implemented. Amazing, thank you !